# How to kill process - DWM.exe temporarilly in Windows 10 Pro 64 bit?

Tags: windows, dwm

I want to kill process DWM.exe in windows 10 temporarilly, because permanently it may cause issues.

**Goal:** using bat file to accomplish this.

Tried this [guide](https://superuser.com/questions/1016170/temporarily-disable-desktop-composition-in-windows-10), didn't work! Problem was at the last step, when I tried to kill DWM.exe. It said access denied, while I launched process explorer as admin.

Thanks for an answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you encounter access deny issue when want to perform a specify action to this executable file. We could take the owner of the .exe file at first. 
Right click dwm.exe in task manager, and choose properties\security\Advanced\Change\type your user account\OK\Apply\Ok\Ok\OK.
Make sure your account have full control right for dwm.exe. If not, also right click it\Properties\Security\Edit\choose your account in Group or user names\Tick full control\Apply\Yes\Ok

Comment: This time i did it exactly in the same way. And at last step after i killed dwm.exe, my screen was black and computer frozen. And classic theme was appearing, i saw it on overlay of chrome.

Comment: I am still trying to disable dwm, i take control of dwm and yet added full control for administrators and my administrator account and it still says access denied.