# access denied when terminating DWM

Tags: dwm

I am trying to terminate dwm on windows 10.


I found this guide:
[Temporarily disable Desktop Composition in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1016170/temporarily-disable-desktop-composition-in-windows-10)

I suspend explorer.exe and than i try to kill dwm, but it says access denied, even i added my administrator account as owner and added permismissions to full control for dwm.

Please help it is important to me.

Comment: That answer also works now. Try without suspending explorer.exe.

Comment: Obviously it doesn't for me, wow that's so helpful. On other forum they provided me with actual answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/6ranln/is_it_worth_disabling_dwm_desktop_composition_for/